# What should return doc.ents if the doc have no entities, in spacy?

Tags: nlp, spacy, implementation

I want to answer this question: "How many sentences contain named entities given a doc?"
and I have this piece of code as solution

```
nb = 0

for sent in list(doc.sents):
    if sent.ents:
        nb = nb+1

print(nb)
```

But I am a little confused about how the if-statement work; 
consider that the actual sentence(sent) does not have any entities(ents), so sent.ents will return an empty list I suppose and I can't understand why an empty list is considered as a false statement because the program when executed does not enter the if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just test whether the tuples entities has any elements:

```py
for sent in list(doc.sents):
    if len(sent.ents) > 0:
        nb = nb+1
```

Edit: For the purpose of evaluating boolean expressions (as in case of `if` statements), empty lists are evaluated as false, even though they don't explicitly equal `False`. Expanding your example with some print statements:

```py
nb = 0
spacy_nlp = spacy.load("de_core_news_md")
text = "Nichts. Auch nichts."
doc = spacy_nlp(text)
for sent in list(doc.sents):
    print("type of ents: " + str(type(sent.ents)) + " with " + str(len(sent.ents)) + " elements.")
    if sent.ents:
        nb = nb+1

print(nb)
```

Results in:

```
type of ents: <class 'list'> with 0 elements.
type of ents: <class 'list'> with 0 elements.
0
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, but this is not what I asked. I am wondering if an empty list returned by sent.ents is considered as false.

Comment: Valid point. I extended the answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: yes this helped.